# PHPMailer and S/MIME

Tags: php, security, phpmailer, digital-certificate, smime

For a school assignment we have to send secure emails coming from a bank (we are the bank). In order to secure these emails im using PHPMailer. 
PHPMailer contains a Sign($cert_filename, $key_filename, $key_pass) method that signs the email using a certificate. I'm guessing that this is making the email 'secure' and that the customer can really know it is the bank sending the email. I'm sending the emails over my own domain using SMTP.

In order to get the certificate i've created a certificate at [this website](http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/free-email-certificate.html), that got installed in my browser.

Now the question is: how do I use that certificate to sign the emails i'm sending using my PHP script and PHPMailer? I've exported the certificate from my browser (FF), which results in a .p12 file, but i think the .p12 file isn't what im looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `openssl` to convert the pkcs12 file (which you probably have) into a .pem certificate for PHPMailer. See this article: http://www.adam-makes-websites.com/discoveries/sending_secure_certified_s-mime_emails_via_php

Comment: Thanks for the help, how can i check wether the email is signed or not? I'm using gmail to check the mails.

Comment: If you view the mail source ("display original") in Gmail, you should see a block of base64 preceded by a header with `Content-Type: multipart/signed;
          protocol="application/pkcs7-signature";`

Comment: Thanks again, I've made all the changes but the emails aren't mareked as signed yet. The body is also empty (white email, but the subject works). If i remove the sign vars the email shows up fine. I'm using SMTP. Any idea?

Comment: Enable `error_reporting`, remove `@` before the `openssl_*` function calls [Marin told you to edit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12886654/345031), or use `set_error_handler("var_dump");` to reveal any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class.phpmailer.php file change a data:

```
public   $sign_cert_file = ’’; 
public   $sign_key_file  = ’’; 
public   $sign_key_pass  = ’’;
```

than locate that appears:

```
if (@openssl_pkcs7_sign($file, $signed, "file://".$this->sign_cert_file, array("file://".$this->sign_key_file, $this->sign_key_pass), null)) {
```

and change to:

```
if (@openssl_pkcs7_sign($file, $signed, file_get_contents($this->sign_cert_file), array(file_get_contents($this->sign_key_file), $this->sign_key_pass), null)){
```

This mean that you got via object $this->sign_key_file instead of file inclusion file://

Than change your temp name:

```
$file = tempnam(’’, ’mail’);
...
$signed = tempnam("", "signed");
```

to:

```
$file = tempnam(’./tmp/’, ’mail’);
...
$signed = tempnam("./tmp/", "signed");
```

This means that you are using on a tmp directory server.

And now how example show of sending and putting cert file of data:

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddAddress("email@example.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test 1";
$mail->Body = "Test 1 of PHPMailer.";

// CUSTOMISED SIGN EMAIL : START
$mail->sign_cert_file="/xxx/key.pem";
$mail->sign_key_file="/xxx/key.pem";
$mail->sign_key_pass="yyy";
// CUSTOMISED SIGN EMAIL : END

$mail->Send(); // Send encrypted email!
```

Comment: I've made all the changes but the emails aren't mareked as signed yet. The body is also empty (white email, but the subject works). If i remove the sign vars the email shows up fine. I'm using SMTP. Any idea?

Comment: Or is encoding problem that due of operation can't process or in a configuration of SSL sign.

Answer (score 1):

You can now add a signed certificate using the `sign()` function:

```
require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddAddress("email@example.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "Test";

$mail->sign(
    'cert.crt',
    'cert.key',
    'password',//required even if empty
    'certchain.pem'
);

if( !$mail->Send() ){
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smime_signed_mail.phps#L77